How to customize docker packaged using gradle bootBuildImage
version:

spring-boot: 3.3.0
jdk: 21
gradle: 8.6

I have a springboot application that I intend to use docker for containerized deployments (mainly for runtime management).
It uses the logback logging framework, which has two appenders configured as follows:
    <substitutionProperty name="log.dir" value="/workspace/logs" />

    <appender name="SYSTEM" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${log.dir}/system.log</File>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>
                ${log.base}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}/system-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder charset="UTF-8">
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level [%thread] [%X{traceId}] %file:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AI-SERVICE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${log.dir}/ai-service.log</File>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>
                ${log.base}/%d{yyyy-MM, aux}/ai-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder charset="UTF-8">
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level [%thread] [%X{traceId}] %file:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

What I was going to do was use -v to map the '/workspace/logs' directory to the host machine directory. This makes it easy to view the different log files configured by the logback framework directly on the host machine.
However, if we use 'gradle bootBuildImage' directly to bundle the image, the container will start with an exception: 'file /workspace/logs not found'.
Is there a good way to solve this problem?
For example, create '/workspace/logs' when using' gradle bootBuildImage 'to bundle the image. How to do it

Is there a specific reason not to log to stdout / stderr? That's the expectation of container orchestrators like kubernetes

At the moment, the main reasons I choose to deploy with docker images are convenience. I don't have to set up a new environment on a new server, and I don't have to use container orchestration tools such as Kubernetes.

The functionality of this springboot application is actually split into several modules that aren't closely related to each other, so I'd prefer to keep the logs separate for easier viewing.

Using Docker alone won't help manage scaling, networking, high availability, security, etc. Using an orchestration service therefore is recommended. In any case, could you push a base image that already has that folder? Then pull from that?

Even in plain Docker, logging to stdout (where docker logs can retrieve logs) is usually a best practice, and avoids the problem you're asking in the question.

Why doesn't -v work? This run command with a Docker container built using gradle bootBuildImage and a logback.xml similar to yours works for me: docker run -it --volume ${PWD}/logs:/workspace/logs myimage. I created the ${PWD}/logs local directory before running the container to make sure the local directory had the correct permissions.
